# Can we make enum multilingual in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, multilingual

I am working on multilingual site and in which i used some enum and now it can be possible that we can make theses enum as per multilingual?

My enum structure is

```
public enum abc
{
  [Description{"multilingual text"}]
  StatucActive = 1
}
```

like this. i want to write multilingual text in description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No we can't use enum as a multilingual but i have an alternate option that is use resource file it working like an enum in some situations.

please try resource file and it will solve your problem....

Answer (score 7):

You should follow the steps:

(1) prepare the resource files e.g. `resource.en-US.resx`/`resource.zh-CN.resx`/etc. Each resource file has keys and values, their keys are the same between files, values are different in languages.

(2) define your own `DescriptionAttribute`, something like this:

```
public class LocalDescriptionAttribute : DescriptionAttribute
{
    public string ResourceKey { get; set; }
    public string CultureCode { get; set; }
    //you can set a default value of CultureCode
    //so that you needn't set it everywhere
    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            //core of this attribute
            //first find the corresponding resource file by CultureCode
            //and then get the description text by the ResourceKey
        }
    }
}
```

The usage:

```
public enum MyTexts
{
    [LocalDescription(CultureCode="zh-CN", ResourceKey="Title")]
    Title = 0,
    [LocalDescription(ResourceKey="Status")]   //default CultureCode
    Status = 1
}
```

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to translate an enumerated would be to create an array of values for each language you want.

String language1[] = {"value","value2"};

String language2[] = {"other value","other value2"};

String multi = language2[enumvalue];

Your enum value become the index to your string array of translations.